# can an xslt template carry both name and match attributes?

Tags: xslt

Is the following (a) allowed (b) useful

```
<xsl:template match="foo" name="bar"> 
</xsl:template>
```

(it means that the template could be triggered either from recursive template processing or directly from `<xsl:call-template name="bar"/>`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply put, yes. I quite often name the identity template and invoke it directly using a `<xsl:call-template name="identity" />`.

It's a useful tool for a form of inheritance; you can define a template to match one node, and another that handles a derivative of that node that does the specifics, then calls the more general template.

For example:

```
<xsl:template match="animal" name="animal">
  <!-- handle any animal related stuff here -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dog">
  <xsl:call-template name="animal" />
  <!-- handle any dog specific stuff here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If an xsl:template element has a name attribute, it may, but need not, also have a match attribute.
From [W3C XSLT specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#named-templates)